# How to enable pagination for Sub Resource?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

In my API config file, I disabled pagination :

`api_platform.yaml` :

```
api_platform:
    collection:
        pagination:
            enabled: false
```

But I want to enable pagination for a specific subresource :

**Parent class :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ForumRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={"get"},
 * )
 */
class Forum
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var ForumSubject[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\ForumSubject",
     *     mappedBy="forum",
     * )
     * @ApiSubresource(maxDepth=1)
     */
    private $subjects;
    ...
```

**Children class :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ForumSubjectRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "post",
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "put",
 *         "delete"
 *     },
 * )
 */
class ForumSubject
{
    ...
```

**Everything works fine** I can access my sub-resources :
`/api/forums/a21cb5db-aed7-45a6-884f-3d3e6d7abd8c/subjects`
(Return all subjects of forum, route name : `api_forums_subjects_get_subresource` ).

But I am unable to enable paging on this route, the documentation does not mention anything.

After research I tried this, **but nothing works** :

**Does not work** in parent or children class :

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     ...
 *     subresourceOperations={
 *         "api_forums_subjects_get_subresource"={"pagination_enabled"=true}
 *     }
```

**Does not work** in parent class ; error un children class (The operation "api_forums_subjects_get_subresource" cannot be found in the Swagger specification).

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     ...
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "api_forums_subjects_get_subresource"={"pagination_enabled"=true}
 *     },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking in the API Platform source code, here is the solution :

In **children** class :

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     ...
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         ...
 *         "api_forums_subjects_get_subresource"={
 *             "method"="get", // don't forget : otherwise trigger a strange swagger error
 *             "pagination_enabled"=true
 *         }
```